# Dll dependency could not be loaded. How to read fuslogvw?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, dll, reference

## Background

---

I'm making a program in C# that uses the default Kinect Fusion demo for 3D scanning. I've added a lot of different stuff to this program, and I'm almost done. It works perfectly via debug on VS2013. I have also created an installer, but when I run the installed application I get some errors, which I'll place here below. I'm using a Japanese version of Windows (8.1 64 bit), which means I have to translate all the errors that get shown to me. This means that the errors I show here may not be 100% logical or correct. I'm also not very experienced with C#, so I could be overlooking some very basic stuff here. So please feel free to ask any question. I might very well be that, since I don't know too much about this stuff, I might have missed something very easy for someone more experienced.

Just a bit more information about the program:

- It's active solution platform is x64 (it still gets installed in x86, not sure if that matters);
- It requires administrator access before running;
- There is another directory in the "Program Files (x86)" with the same name (3D-Scanner) that contains a different application needed for floor removal. Does this maybe mess with look-up/search possibilities? My original plan was for them to go in the same map, but the system creates two of the same maps;
- The default Kinect Fusion program I'm using is 64 bit. I had some trouble with this before since my application wasn't able to create an installer with a 64 bit reference as a 32bit project. I switched it to a 64 bit project and the installer seems to work fine (except for the missing dll reference).

## Errors

---

When the application crashes and I start debugging it with VS2013 I get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll

Additional information: 
    file or assembly 'Microsoft.Kinect.Fusion, Version = 2.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 31bf3856ad364e35', or one of its dependencies could not be loaded. 
    Manifest definition of the found assembly does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

When I open it up in VS2013 I also get the message "The call stack contains only external code". When I disabled "Just My Code" I basically got shown some machine code language or whatever it was. I don't think it was very relevant so I won't place it here. If there is a need to see this code please inform me and I'll post it here.

The following is listed as the "Call stack with external code" (I have to use an image, because the call stack was not copy-able):
[image: Call stack with external code]

## What have I tried

---

Well after some reading around I of course found that I get this error due to the fact that there is a reference/dependency missing from the program. This is kind of weird to me since it works in debugging. Anyhow I tried to set forth and try and find what it was that I was missing. I've used [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on the file to see what it would bring up, but I couldn't make much of it. It was such a huge amount of data, and I have not clue what I'm looking for.

So I fired up [Fuslogvw.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx) to see if I could find some errors that way. It certainly got me closer. The output seems to be a lot more logical, but I still don't know what I'm looking for. Again please note that since I'm working on a Japanese system, I have had to translate these logs, which is why the logs look a bit off. Here's the output for the of the `Microsoft.Kinect.Fusion` dll (which is the one I assume is causing troubles) on the *working* debug version of the program:

```
 *** Assembly bind log entry (2015/08/24 @ 10:38:40) ***

 We were successful in the operation.
 Bind Result:. Hr = 0x0 I The operation completed successfully.

 Assembly manager to read from: C: \ Windows \ Microsoft.NET \ Framework64 \ v4.0.30319 \ clr.dll
 It is running under the executable file.  C: \ Users \ bono \ Documents \ Visual Studio 2013 \ Projects \ 3D-Scanner \ 3D-Scanner \ bin \ x64 \ Release \ 3D-Scanner.vshost.exe
 --- Detailed error log is as follows.

 === Pre-bind state information ===
 Log: DisplayName = Microsoft.Kinect.Fusion, Version = 2.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 31bf3856ad364e35
  (Fully-specified)
 Log: Appbase = file: /// C: / Users / bono / documents / visual studio 2013 / Projects / 3D-Scanner / 3D-Scanner / bin / x64 / Release /
 Log: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
 Log: Dynamic Base = NULL
 Log: Cache Base = NULL
 Log: AppName = 3D-Scanner.vshost.exe
 the calling assembly: 3D-Scanner, Version = 1.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null
 ===
 Log: This bind starts in read context of default.
 Log: The application configuration file C: I use the \ Users \ bono \ documents \ visual studio 2013 \ Projects \ 3D-Scanner \ 3D-Scanner \ bin \ x64 \ Release \ 3D-Scanner.vshost.exe.Config.
 Log: I use the host configuration file.
 Log: C: I use the computer configuration file from the \ Windows \ Microsoft.NET \ Framework64 \ v4.0.30319 \ config \ machine.config.
 Log: reference after policy: Microsoft.Kinect.Fusion, Version = 2.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 31bf3856ad364e35
 Log: I failed to GAC look up.
 Log: A new URL file: /// C: / Users / bono / documents / visual studio 2013 / Projects / 3D-Scanner / 3D-Scanner / bin / x64 / Release / Microsoft.Kinect.Fusion.DLL and trying to download You.
 Log: I succeeded in downloading the assembly.  The next file you are trying to set up: C: \ Users \ bono \ documents \ visual studio 2013 \ Projects \ 3D-Scanner \ 3D-Scanner \ bin \ x64 \ Release \ Microsoft.Kinect.Fusion.dll
 Log: I went into the setup phase of execution from the source.
 Log: assembly name Microsoft.Kinect.Fusion, Version = 2.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, is PublicKeyToken = 31bf3856ad364e35.
 Log: I succeeded to bind.  C: it will return the \ Users \ bono \ documents \ visual studio 2013 \ Projects \ 3D-Scanner \ 3D-Scanner \ bin \ assembly from x64 \ Release \ Microsoft.Kinect.Fusion.dll.
 Error: the assembly has been loaded in the default read context.
```

Here is the version of the *non-working* installed version of the program:

```
 *** Assembly bind log entry (2015/08/24 @ 10:34:17) ***

 It failed in operation.
 Bind Result:. Hr = 0x80131040 but there is no description.

 Assembly manager to read from: C: \ Windows \ Microsoft.NET \ Framework64 \ v4.0.30319 \ clr.dll
 It is running under the executable file.  C: \ Program Files (x86) \ 3D-Scanner \ 3D-Scanner \ 3D-Scanner.exe
 --- Detailed error log is as follows.

 === Pre-bind state information ===
 Log: DisplayName = Microsoft.Kinect.Fusion, Version = 2.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 31bf3856ad364e35
  (Fully-specified)
 Log: Appbase = file: /// C: / Program Files (x86) / 3D-Scanner / 3D-Scanner /
 Log: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
 Log: Dynamic Base = NULL
 Log: Cache Base = NULL
 Log: AppName = 3D-Scanner.exe
 the calling assembly: 3D-Scanner, Version = 1.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null
 ===
 Log: This bind starts in read context of default.
 Log: The application configuration file C: I use the \ Program Files (x86) \ 3D-Scanner \ 3D-Scanner \ 3D-Scanner.exe.Config.
 Log: I use the host configuration file.
 Log: C: I use the computer configuration file from the \ Windows \ Microsoft.NET \ Framework64 \ v4.0.30319 \ config \ machine.config.
 Log: reference after policy: Microsoft.Kinect.Fusion, Version = 2.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 31bf3856ad364e35
 Log: I failed to GAC look up.
 Log: A new URL file: /// C: / Program Files I am trying to download the (x86) /3D-Scanner/3D-Scanner/Microsoft.Kinect.Fusion.DLL.
 Log: I succeeded in downloading the assembly.  The next file you are trying to set up: C: \ Program Files (x86) \ 3D-Scanner \ 3D-Scanner \ Microsoft.Kinect.Fusion.dll
 Log: I went into the setup phase of execution from the source.
 Log: assembly name Microsoft.Kinect.Fusion, Version = 0.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, is PublicKeyToken = null.
 Warning: The results of the comparison of the assembly name, mismatch of Major Version found.
 Error: assembly references, it did not match the found assembly definition.
 Error: set-up phase of execution from the source failed (hr = 0x80131040).
 Error: Could not complete the setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040).  Survey it was canceled.
```

I think the missing information is in there somewhere, but I don't know how to make sense of it. I would appreciate any help when it comes to picking out the useful information.

## Additional Information

---

I'm not sure if this is completely necessary, but I thought it might be worth it to show my installer files. Maybe I've missed including something in there that causes this missing dll reference. I just use all available files (as far as I'm aware) as destination files, but I might be missing something.

[image: installer files]

Comment: What is the version of Microsoft.Kinect.Fusion.dll available in the installed path. It looks like there is a version mismatch.

Comment: @Taleeb Hmm, I think for some reason that might be `0.0.0.0` (I assume I can check via: properties -> most right tab -> File version?).

Comment: Yes - the version mentioned in the logs is 0.0.0.0 as well (while it is expecting version 2.0.0.0). Personally I've no idea about Microsoft.Kinect.Fusion... but can you copy the dll from your working environment to the non working environment - this would hopefully resolve your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an issue of version mismatch. The logs from the non-working environment says that the version found is 0.0.0.0 while the expected version is 2.0.0.0.

```
Log: assembly name Microsoft.Kinect.Fusion, Version = 0.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, is PublicKeyToken = null.
Warning: The results of the comparison of the assembly name, mismatch of Major Version found.
Error: assembly references, it did not match the found assembly definition.
Error: set-up phase of execution from the source failed (hr = 0x80131040).
Error: Could not complete the setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040).  Survey it was canceled.
```

To resolve the issue - copy the correct version of the dll to the non-working environment.

Comment: Well that was _a lot_ more easy than I expected it would be. I saw it was a mismatch, but thought it was due to the missing reference or whatever. Copying different versions in to the install directory worked (not all of them did, but I found one). I've forcefully put it in the the installer project output files, and after install it works now. Thanks!