# Unable to load DLL 'pjsua2' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-6.0, pjsip, .net-runtime

I have created a dll following [AaronReynoldsUK / PJSIP-PJSUA2-CSharp](https://github.com/AaronReynoldsUK/PJSIP-PJSUA2-CSharp) & used it in my WPF application. which was built and worked as expected. after, I published it(*tried Msix packaging/ClickOnce/folder*) It ran fine on my pc but after I send it to other Windows pcs, It failed to start on some windows regardless of their versions. checked all the framework dependencies & installed it on those pcs, The issue remained unchanged. when I checked their windows event viewer, I found the following error(***summarized***),

[image]

> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'pjsua2' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)

This error is only visible on the PCs where The App failed to build.

**FYI: I am calling all the methods code-behind. Project is built targetting x86 and compiled & published using x86. Also, In the project reference, assembly Copy Local was True.**

Please, feel free to ask if you need any more info or to give any suggestions.

Full Error Details:

**Provider: .Net Runtime**

```
    CoreCLR Version: 6.0.1322.58009
   .NET Version: 6.0.13
    Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
    Exception Info: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'MYAPP.Views.Container' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '10' and line position '5'.
    ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MYAPP.Services.SIPServices.Sip.SipManager' threw an exception.
    ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'pjsua2PINVOKE' threw an exception.
    ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'SWIGExceptionHelper' threw an exception.
    ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'pjsua2' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)
    at pjsua2PINVOKE.SWIGExceptionHelper.SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacks_pjsua2(ExceptionDelegate applicationDelegate, ExceptionDelegate arithmeticDelegate, ExceptionDelegate divideByZeroDelegate, ExceptionDelegate indexOutOfRangeDelegate, ExceptionDelegate invalidCastDelegate, ExceptionDelegate invalidOperationDelegate, ExceptionDelegate ioDelegate, ExceptionDelegate nullReferenceDelegate, ExceptionDelegate outOfMemoryDelegate, ExceptionDelegate overflowDelegate, ExceptionDelegate systemExceptionDelegate)
    at pjsua2PINVOKE.SWIGExceptionHelper..cctor() in E:\rnd23Jan\MYAPP\MYAPP\Services\SIPServices\Classes\pjsua2PINVOKE.cs:line 104
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at pjsua2PINVOKE.SWIGExceptionHelper..ctor()
    at pjsua2PINVOKE..cctor() in E:\rnd23Jan\MYAPP\MYAPP\Services\SIPServices\Classes\pjsua2PINVOKE.cs:line 124
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at pjsua2PINVOKE.new_Endpoint()
    at Endpoint..ctor() in E:\rnd23Jan\MYAPP\MYAPP\Services\SIPServices\Classes\Endpoint.cs:line 52
    at MYAPP.Services.SIPServices.Sip.SipManager..cctor() in E:\rnd23Jan\MYAPP\MYAPP\Services\SIPServices\Sip\SipManager.cs:line 26
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at MYAPP.Services.SIPServices.Sip.SipManager..ctor(EpConfig config, pjsip_transport_type_e tType) in E:\rnd23Jan\MYAPP\MYAPP\Services\SIPServices\Sip\SipManager.cs:line 72
    at MYAPP.Services.PjServices.Sip.SipSingletone..ctor() in E:\rnd23Jan\MYAPP\MYAPP\Services\PjServices\Sip\SipSingletone.cs:line 14
    at MYAPP.Services.PjServices.Sip.SipSingletone.get_GetSipInstance() in E:\rnd23Jan\MYAPP\MYAPP\Services\PjServices\Sip\SipSingletone.cs:line 23
    at MYAPP.Views.Container..ctor() in E:\rnd23Jan\MYAPP\MYAPP\Views\Container.xaml.cs:line 56
    at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
    at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
    at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
    at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
    at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(Stream stream, ParserContext pc)
    at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Uri resourceLocator, Boolean bSkipJournaledProperties)
    at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
    at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(Object unused)
    at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
    at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
    at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
    at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
    at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(Object obj)
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
    at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
    at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
    at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
    at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
    at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
    at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
    at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
    at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
    at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
    at System.Windows.Application.Run()
    at MYAPP.App.Main()
```

**Provider: Application Error**

```
    Faulting application name: MyApp.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x6387d16c
    Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.19041.572, time stamp: 0x979ddb1d
    Exception code: 0xe0434352
    Fault offset: 0x00129ab2
    Faulting process id: 0xb8c
    Faulting application start time: 0x01d92f1948c04dcc
    Faulting application path: C:\Users\TestVm\Desktop\net6.0-windows10.0.22621.0\MyApp.exe
    Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
    Report Id: 88fd7660-b834-434b-8b37-58626cb7408b
    Faulting package full name: 
    Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Comment: Since it is working on some machines I would check requirements at following webpage : https://www.pjsip.org/docs/book-latest/html/intro_pjsua2.html

Comment: Can you please indicate exactly which point you are referring to? I've gone through the doc several times and did everything accordingly.

Comment: I suggest digging into the fusion logs. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32173455/dll-dependency-could-not-be-loaded-how-to-read-fuslogvw&ved=2ahUKEwiK4PjM-en8AhWQCN4KHfL7AqoQFnoECAoQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0VzHAaHV4pY9mQQzwikH8F It is possible that the DLL was found but could not be loaded for various reasons, such as x86/64 missing native deps, file permissions etc...

Comment: I said the Requirements paragraph.

Comment: The [docs](https://www.pjsip.org/docs/book-latest/html/intro_pjsua2.html#building-pjsua2) mention "Standard C++ library is required".  It mentions mingw, but that is not accurate.  Running dumpbin.exe /imports pjsua2.dll reveals the truth, you have a dependency on the Visual C++ runtime, specifically msvcp140.dll, vcruntime140.dll and vcruntime140_1.dll.  Download and run the [vcredist installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170#visual-studio-2015-2017-2019-and-2022) or copy these files into the .exe install directory.

Comment: If @Hans suggestion didn't work, check whether the project is running on *AnyCpu* even though it's been set up for x86.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you everyone for contributing to this issue. It was a really big help. However, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420595/how-to-add-external-native-dependency-dll) helped me export specific DLLs & referencing thus solving the problem.

Also, In the C++ project properties I had to Change "Copy to Output Directory" for all the project dependencies.